# Problem while trying to insert multiple values to Sqlite database

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, sqlite

I have to make a request to a Brazil ZIPCODES API to get JSON data and insert it on a sqlite database using python. I'm currenctly using pycharm but I need to insert a lot of columns, but somehow the code don't insert the values. Here's the code

```
import requests
import sqlite3
import json

CEPC = input("Please type the zipcode:")

print("Identifying the ZIP CODE")

Requisicao = requests.get(f"https://viacep.com.br/ws/{CEPC}/json")

if Requisicao.status_code == 200:
    data = Requisicao.json()
    # Database
    con = sqlite3.connect("Banco de dados/CEPS.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Requisicao")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Requisicao (cep, logradouro, bairro, uf, ddd, siafi, 
    validation, created json)")

    cur.executemany("insert into Requisicao values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (data["cep"], 
    json.dumps(data)))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
else:
    print(f"Request failed with status code {Requisicao.status_code} ")
```

**The outpout of the zipcode is:**

```
{
  "cep": "05565-000",
  "logradouro": "Avenida General Asdrúbal da Cunha",
  "complemento": "",
  "bairro": "Jardim Arpoador",
  "localidade": "São Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004",
  "ddd": "11",
  "siafi": "7107"
}
```

I need to insert all of these columns: "cep, logadouro, complemento, bairro, localidade, uf, ibge, gia, ddd, siafi".When I try to run the code, It gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Gui\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 19, in <module>
cur.executemany("insert into Requisicao values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (data["cep"], 
json.dumps(data)))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement 
uses 8, and there are 9 supplied
```

When I try to put the exact same value of columns with the "?", the errors says that "uses 8, and there are 7 supplied.

Comment: you are supplying only 8 values, but when creating data base you used 9 columns, so you are facing the issue, add one more `?` in cur.executemany(insert into)  line

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already did it, every time I put the exact same value of columns and the "?" it gives the error, with a lower value. like this: cur.executemany("insert into Requisicao values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (data["cep"], json.dumps(data)))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 8, and there are 9 supplied.

Comment: `cep, logradouro, bairro, uf, ddd, siafi, validation, created json` Is that part correct? You want to make a column called `created` that has a data type of `json`?

Comment: Robson, I want to create a column for each of those informations: "cep, logradouro, bairro, uf, ddd, siafi, validation, created. So there'll be a column called: Cep, and one called logradouro and it comes to the next ones. And everyone of them must have their respective values. So for example: The column cep would have the value: "05565-000", just like in the example of zipcode

Comment: What would be the values for `validation` and `created`?

Comment: The column validation would be boolean, and it will be filled with true or false( I'm going to implement it later, the code will check if the data is correct and then insert those values on validation). About the created will be a column with the hour we make the request. I just need to insert the values on the other ones

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what fields you have in your table, if you want to insert all the data from the JSON that's 10 fields and if you want to add validation/created fields that would mean a total of 12 fields. The first 10 fields you can get from the JSON but it's not clear where the values for the last 2 will come from, or when they'll be added to the data. P.S. Why didn't you mark the code you've posted here as the answer to your previous question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will insert all 10 values from the JSON into the table Requisicao and 0 for both validation and created, though that can be changed.

```py
import requests
import sqlite3
import json

CEPC = input("Please type the zipcode:")

print("Identifying the ZIP CODE")

Requisicao = requests.get(f"https://viacep.com.br/ws/{CEPC}/json")

if Requisicao.status_code == 200:
    data = Requisicao.json()
    # Database
    con = sqlite3.connect("CEPS.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Requisicao")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Requisicao (cep,logradouro,complemento,bairro,localidade,uf,ibge,gia,ddd,siafi, validation, created)")
    cur.execute("insert into Requisicao values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",tuple(data.values())+(0, 0))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
else:
    print(f"Request failed with status code {Requisicao.status_code} ")
```

Comment: Thank you! It's also working, both of you guys saved my life!